# struct rest *r_list expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm making a restore management program. I want to delete a value corresponding to rlist[index - 1] in a pointer array dynamically assigned to detail_an_item(), but I get this error. How do I fix the error?

```
struct rest {
    char food[TSIZE]; // case : Aglio e Olio
    char kind; // case : R
    int price; // case : 14000
};

void delete_an_item(struct rest *r_list, size_t *ptr_r_items){
// input_int() Defined and declared.
index = input_int(); // ex. index = 6 The actual [] number is 5.
    if ((index >= 0 && index < *ptr_r_items) && index == 1){
        r_list[index - 1].food = NULL; // error here
        r_list[index - 1].kind = '\0';
        r_list[index - 1].price = 0;
```

I don't know how to solve the error. Tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

1. `index` is not defined in this function/
2. You can't assign to the array.
3. I do not understand `index - 1` but probably it translates 1 based indexes to the C indexes (starting from 0)
4. `(index >= 0 && index < *ptr_r_items) && index == 1)` will evaluate to the `true` only if `index == 1`

```
struct rest {
    char food[TSIZE];
    char kind;
    int price;
};

void delete_an_item(struct rest *r_list, size_t *ptr_r_items)
{
    size_t index = input_int();
    if ((index >= 0 && index < *ptr_r_items) && index == 1){
        r_list[index - 1].food[0] = 0;  //food is now an empty string
        r_list[index - 1].kind = '\0';
        r_list[index - 1].price = 0;
    }
}
```